# How can I increase server SSL performance

Tags: netty, sslengine

I've enabled SSL on my proxy server and found that the performance has dropped from around 17k requests per second to 5k request per second.  I followed the code in Netty's secure chat example and I don't think I've done anything differently.

I've written a dummy server to see if I've made some mistakes on my proxy.  Running the dummy SSL server in normal http mode is capable of around 50k request per second.  When I enable SSL on the dummy server that drops to 28k requests per second.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using JDK 6 to compile the code, running on JDK 7u4.  I'm using Netty-3.5.0 as well.
I'm using zeusbench to run the test.  The test parameters are: zeusbench -n 10000 -c 100 -k -C RC4_SHA "https:///"

Source: http://pastebin.com/iahqr3zT

**Edit 1:** I've run the dummy server through JProfiler.
The SSLContext.createSSLEngine call in the pipeline factory takes (on average) 55,005 microseconds (that average has been calculated from 540 invocations of the method).

The SslHandler.handshake call in channelConnected takes (on average) 46,284 microseconds (that average has been calculated from 540 invocations of the method).

I understand there isn't much Netty can do about the call to createSSLEngine, but could the SslHandler.handshake be tuned any better?  Its taking almost as long as the generation of the engine itself.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to terminate the SSL before the request is reaching your server? Ideally you could use dedicated hardware to terminate the SSL. Amazons Elastic Load Balancer can do this as well. What is the length of the SSL key? The length of the key has impact on performance http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_key_length.shtml

Comment: @JohnP Thanks for the reply.  Terminating the SSL before reaching my server is not a possibility.  Thanks for the tip on the length of the SSL key, its 2048

Answer (score 0):

Encryption/Decryption w/ java is really slow.
You should not use SSL implementation w/ java for the performance.
There are several ways to avoid java for SSL connection:

1. Configure proxy server which provide SSL connection infront of your
   java server
2. Implement ssl handshaking library w/ openssl use the library in netty code by jni

Comment: Really slow compared to what? There are millions of websites running e.g. Tomcat with SSL that are counter-examples to these assertions. I've been running one myself for several years.

Comment: Here's one source for the "java is slow" comment in this answer: http://netty.io/wiki/requirements-for-4.x.html#benefits-of-using-openssl

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-using ssl sessions for existing connections, this reduces the ssl handshake and should give you a general boost.

Comment: This already happens by default. You have to go well out of your way to prevent it.