# Slow Java SSL in a netty application

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I'm experiencing a significant performance degradation using netty's `SslHandler` vs an external SSL terminator like stud or stunnel. The difference is about 100ms in time to complete the handshake. I requested the same resource from my application several hundred times via httperf and made sure that the same cipher (DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA) was used in each case.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896502/how-can-i-increase-server-ssl-performance) got no accepted answers, but the comments indicated that running an SSL terminator in front of a Java process might be a good idea.

Is this expected behavior? Is Java's SSL implementation known to be this much slower, or is it possible that I have some setting configured improperly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it's known to be slow, compared to openssl,.. You could try to use native openssl bindings like twitter does:

https://github.com/twitter/finagle/tree/master/finagle-native

This is one reason for apr and SSL:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html#HTTPS

Comment: Java's SSL implementation is known to be slow?Where is a backing reference for this?

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear.. its "slow" compared to openssl. This is also one reason why tomcat use its native providers for openssl if it can be found... Thanks for the comments and remind me to make it more clear and add another link.

Answer (score 6):

Netty folks recommend openssl over JDK SSL for couple of reasons, performance is one of them. Explanation can be found on their wiki:

http://netty.io/wiki/requirements-for-4.x.html#benefits-of-using-openssl